# Apache Memory Leak - no PHP used

Tags: apache, powershell, apache2.2

My Apache 2.2 module (Windows) seem to be liking memory, Task Manager shows constant growth in memory until ~2GB are reached, then it crashes.  I am not using PHP at all, this is not a website but a module acting as a server.  A number of barcode scanning devices will send request to this server, and this server will do inserts, updates, deletes, queries on database.  I am seeing the issue if I have 10-15 devices working at the same time.

I am using FastMM to detect memory leaks in my Apache module and FastMM is not reporting any leaks.  If I intentionally introduce one, I can see a leak being cought by FastMM.

That tells me that Apache is not releasing memory to OS and this happens under certain circumstances only. If I have 1-2 devices only, then this issue is not happening. So, my guess is that it is caused by high number of requests sent to Apache.

As a temporary solution, I am using PowerShell (version 2.0 or 4.0, depending on machine) script to restart Apache when a memory threshold is reached.  My PowerShell script is doing this to stop apache process and service and to start it (if memory has reached ca 0.8GB) and this all works, I tested it:

```
# If working set of httpd or httpd#1 is greater than threshold, stop and start
if($procobj.workingset -gt $Threshold)
{
# $ProcName is name of process reported by PowerShell (as httpd, httpd#1, httpd#2, ...)
echo $("Memory for " + $ProcName + " exceeds Threshold");

# Stop httpd process
stop-process -name $MyHTTPD -force

# Stop service $ServiceName (this is name of service in Windows->Services)
echo $("---> Stopping service: " + $ServiceName);
stop-Service $ServiceName;

# Start service $ServiceName (this is name of service in Windows->Services)
echo $("---> Starting service: " + $ServiceName);
start-Service $ServiceName;
}
```

As you can see, I am stopping httpd process, then stopping Apache service, then starting the service which will spawn new httpd process.

Also, here are the Apache settings I am using:

```
#Commented out these 3 in httpd.conf
#KeepAlive On
#MaxKeepAliveRequests 0
#KeepAliveTimeout 3000

#these are in mod_mpm
# WinNT MPM
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
ThreadsPerChild 300
#MaxRequestsPerChild 0
MaxRequestsPerChild 50
#According to Apache documentation, if you get "An operation was
#attempted on something that is not a socket), you should use this to
#disable AcceptEx() WinSock v2 API. See:
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_winnt.html
Win32DisableAcceptEx
</IfModule>
```

I am aware that this should be temporary solution but right now, the problem is that I can not detect any leaks although Task Manager shows constant growth in memory.

Much Appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am experiencing exactly the same as you, and I have also checked my server software for leaks with Memproof and found nothing except in the Windows kernel. I use MaxRequestsPerChild set to 1000000 with 1500 threads per child. With Apache 2.4 I don't have to use a powershell script to reset it - Apache does what your script does automatically for me. This may be a problem with the way Windows (or Apache) handles connections that overlap. I am guessing, however, and the solution we're using works fine for now. Perhaps this doesn't happen on a Linux server arrangement, but my server software only runs on Windows! Regards.